# no 'enable wireless' option in network settings

Tags: wireless

After a repair (motherboard replacement) *and BIOS update* for my Lenovo yoga 2 pro, I can no longer connect via wireless. The option is simply missing from the dropdown where it was previously present:

[image: no option to enable wireless]
(the 'Wired connection 1' is my USB-Tethered smartphone)

Reading up on this issue a bit, I've looked in BIOS, where it says that wireless is enabled:

[image]

And I've also checked, that a wireless interface is available and not blocked (hardware block was an issue with earlier Ubuntu versions for this laptop):

```
elrudi@yoga:~$ rfkill list all
0: ideapad_wlan: Wireless LAN
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
1: ideapad_bluetooth: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: yes
    Hard blocked: no
2: hci0: Bluetooth
    Soft blocked: no
    Hard blocked: no
```

Strangely, trying to active the wireless lan interface gives an error:

```
elrudi@yoga:~$ ifconfig wlan0 up
wlan0: ERROR while getting interface flags: No such device
elrudi@yoga:~$
```

There is one 'additional driver' in use:
[image: additional driver]

The output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` is empty. When running `lspci` the output is the following:

```
elrudi@yoga:~$ lspci
00:00.0 Host bridge: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT DRAM Controller (rev 09)
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
00:03.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation Haswell-ULT HD Audio Controller (rev 09)
00:04.0 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation Device 0a03 (rev 09)
00:14.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB xHCI HC (rev 04)
00:16.0 Communication controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series HECI #0 (rev 04)
00:1b.0 Audio device: Intel Corporation 8 Series HD Audio Controller (rev 04)
00:1d.0 USB controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series USB EHCI #1 (rev 04)
00:1f.0 ISA bridge: Intel Corporation 8 Series LPC Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.2 SATA controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series SATA Controller 1 [AHCI mode] (rev 04)
00:1f.3 SMBus: Intel Corporation 8 Series SMBus Controller (rev 04)
00:1f.6 Signal processing controller: Intel Corporation 8 Series Thermal (rev 04)
elrudi@yoga:~$
```

`sudo lshw -class network` only shows an ethernet interface:

```
elrudi@yoga:~$ sudo lshw -class network
  *-network               
       description: Ethernet interface
       physical id: 3
       logical name: enp0s20u2
       serial: 02:64:70:6c:6a:06
       capabilities: ethernet physical
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=rndis_host driverversion=22-Aug-2005 firmware=RNDIS device ip=192.168.42.78 link=yes multicast=yes
```

And the output of `lsusb`:

```
elrudi@yoga:~$ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 011: ID 5986:0535 Acer, Inc 
Bus 002 Device 012: ID 04f3:016f Elan Microelectronics Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 007: ID 2047:0855 Texas Instruments Invensense Embedded MotionApp HID Sensor
Bus 002 Device 005: ID 8087:07dc Intel Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 013: ID 22b8:2e24 Motorola PCS 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
elrudi@yoga:~$
```

With that, I've come to the end of where I think I could look and from what I've found in similar questions asked online. Logging out and in has no effect, neither do changing BIOS settings and `rfkill`ing to unblock interfaces (which are not blocked, as shown above). There is no 'Secure boot' option to turn off in BIOS (as was suggested in some other threads).

Any suggestions as to where I could look? As the repair shop told me they updated the BIOS, I'm thinking there might be a setting there that I need to change.

Thanks!

---

PS for completeness, the other relevant BIOS-page. On this page, I've tried disabling the 'Lenovo fast boot' option (here still set):

[image]

The 'security' tab has the option of setting some passwords (which are all not set)

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A2` terminal command.

Comment: You probably did not scroll the full output. Run straight `lspci` without `-knn`.

Comment: I do not see any wired or wireless adapters. I would suspect that they forgot to install one, but rfkill is showing something.

Comment: Thanks Pilot6 for your requests for additional information... any suggestions of what I could try to do? 'Reinstall the OS' is something that reminds me of the windows days :)

Comment: Run `sudo lshw -class network`

Comment: And also disable Secure Boot if there is this option in Security.

Comment: Added the information. Secure boot is not listed in the bios anywhere.

Comment: I think the wireless adapter is not istalled or has a bad contact. You need to go back to where the laptop was repaired.

Comment: I thought that too initially, but the bluetooth connection is working without any problems, and apparently that's on the same hardware element connected via the same band cable... I'll still ask them just in case. 
   
            
With 'not installed' you mean not installed in software? I did not reinstall anything when I received the laptop back from the shop - is there a way to force a reinstalling of certain software components? Is it possibly necessary?

Comment: Run `lsusb` then. Let's see what is there.

Comment: It looks like you have an Intel eireless adapter, but it is not detected by PCI bus. It may be defective.

Comment: (I've also added the output of `ifconfig wlan0 up`)